# How can I expose ICMP ports in a hook?

Tags: juju

I've got one question regarding Ubuntu Juju deployment, on AWS cloud. I'm using Bash to write my hooks. At the end of the install hook/script, I have lines that expose some of my TCP ports(80,443,5666 etc)

Syntax:

```
open-port 80/tcp
open-port 443/tcp
```

My question is how can I expose ICMP ports in a similar manner? ICMP ECHO request, ICMP ECHO reply is what I need.

The reason for this is that we use Nagios for monitoring of our EC2 instances. Alarms fire off right away, complaining that instance is not reachable, since Nagios relies on ICMP for basic remote host check.

Comment: Nitpicking, ICMP does not have ports. Ports are provided by TCP or UDP or SCTP. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792 for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Juju in AWS uses EC2 security groups. Though the security groups can be made to allow ICMP with the EC2 API or Console, there are no hooks anywhere in the Juju code to do so. The only hooks that exist are for TCP and UDP.

If you have access to the EC2 console, you can find the relevant security group and allow ICMP there.

Or, if you have the credentials configured for the ec2-api-tools, you can use a command like:

`ec2-authorize <group> -P icmp -t -1:-1 -s 0.0.0.0/0`

In Juju [bug 833064](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/833064), they mention an intent to switch to machine-level firewalling (iptables on the instance) rather than continuing to limit themselves to the platform's firewalling capabilities and APIs.